# Applying L'Hopital's rule in $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln x$

Tags: limits, derivatives

I'm trying to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln x$, and here's what I got so far:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x \ln x \\
= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{x}}
$$
and I wanted to apply L'Hopitals rule for that. However, the Wikipedia page of LH rule [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) says that for the rule to work, both functions on the numerator and the denominator must be defined on a open interval containing the limit point, in this case, $0$. But since $\ln x$ isn't defined for negative x, does the rule really work in my case?

Comment: Notice you are approaching the limit of $x$ approaching $0$ from the right (denoted by $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$. Thus this special case only requires the functions to be defined on a some interval $(0,a)$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: From that Wikipedia page: *“Let I be an open interval containing c ... **or an open interval with endpoint c** (for a one-sided limit)”*

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in the limit $\lim_{x\to0^{\color{red}+}}x\ln x$ here, then your function only has to be defined on some interval $(0,a)$ for some $a>0$. Since it is in fact defined in $(0,\infty)$, you have no problem here.