# Hey, how do you calculate this the easiest (not necessarily quickest) way? $\lim_{ x\to1-} (1-x)^{\sin (\pi x)}$

Tags: limits

Please help me, I have no idea and exams are coming soon :( [what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgZsm.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: How can you have NO idea? Seriously. What techniques have you seen in lecture and in previous homework questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using Taylor series. First, let $f(x) = sin(\pi x)$.

Around a number $a$, a function $f$ can be approximated by:

$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) = \sum_n \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n
\end{aligned}
$

In our case, around $a=1$ (since $x \to 1^-$), and stopping the expansion at order 1 we get:

$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= \sum_n \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^n \\
&\approx f(1) + f'(1)(x-1)
\end{aligned}
$

Moreover,

$
\begin{aligned}
&f(1) = sin(\pi) = 0 \\
&f'(1) = \pi cos(\pi) = - \pi
\end{aligned}
$

Therefore,

$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) = sin(\pi x) \approx \pi (1 - x)
\end{aligned}
$

You can verify this is true for a value of $x$ close to 1.

e.g. $sin(\pi * 1.001) \approx \pi (1 - 1.001)$

Finally,

$
\begin{aligned}
\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} (1-x)^{sin(\pi x)} &\approx \lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} (1-x)^{\pi (1 - x)} \\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} \big((1-x)^{(1 - x)}\big)^\pi \\
&= \lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} \big(e^{(1-x)ln(1 - x)}\big)^\pi \\
&= 1^\pi \\
&= 1
\end{aligned}
$

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I needed!

Comment: I updated the answer because maybe it wasn't clear how $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} (1-x)^{(1-x)} = 1$. It's the same thing as $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x^x = 1$. This is true because $x^x = e^{xln(x)}$, and $xln(x)$ goes to zero when $x \to 0$ because $x$ goes faster to zero than $ln(x)$ goes towards $-\infty$. So it ends up being $e^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you already know. For example, setting $y=1-x$ and taking logarithms is quick if you know [$\lim_{y\to0^+}y\ln y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3532732/applying-lhopitals-rule-in-lim-x-to-0-x-ln-x) and [$\lim _{y\to0}\frac{\sin(\pi y)}{\pi y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084660/showing-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-0-fracx-sin-x-1-without-lhopital) (both links found in caase you don't with [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/)).